# SNMP data won't get written to bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, snmp

I'm quite new at stackoverflow, so this is probably stupid question, but here it goes.

I have this string

```
"RTU : Viavi OTU (192.168.1.202)Alarm type: OPTICALTimestamp: Oct 18 2016 - 15:26"
```

that Trap receiver gets from device. Using same receiver I'm flagging this as one parameter and passing it to batch file.

There I just write simple echo command.

```
echo %* >> C:\snmp\message\trap.txt
```

Unfortunatelly message doesn't get through. If I pause it I can see that I get:

```
"RTU : Viavi OTU (192.168.1.202) >> C:\snmp\message\trap.txt
```

Question: What can go wrong? Is it possible that there is some character that lies before 'Alarm' which breaks parameter of echo command? Please, help.

Thanks

Comment: you probably have `\r` chars in between yes. How do you get the original string? Maybe it could directly be redirected to the file.

Comment: I have tested it with a batch-file with `@echo off` and `echo %* >> myfile.txt` in it. Using cmd I passed the string (copy&pasted from question) as argument and it was correctly placed in the file. Have you tried placing single-quotes around the whole string (including the double quotes)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
This is given by device from another part of city which follows connectivity of network. This particular message is sent when break occurs. I don't know the original string, and I'm not sure if I can redirect it.
Yes, when I do it manualy (copy&paste) I also get good result. But string is given from Receiver software. I'm going to try \r and quotes solution...